# Debian package with init.d without autostart

Tags: linux, debian, daemon, packaging, init.d

I'm trying to create a package which contains the init.d file, but doesn't try to start the daemon right after the installation.

Currently, I'm using scripts created from the dh_make template. Right after installation, dpkg wants to start the service. I'd like to stop it from doing that - the daemon will be always started / stopped manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `rules` file, change `dh_installinit` to run with the `-n` option which doesn't modify the postinst and postrm automatically. You will need to do `update-rc.d` yourself to create the rc links though.